# root.destroy() doesn't do destroy my window

Tags: python, tkinter

I'm doing the program that is required to direct to the other window after clicking the button in the current window, and the current window will be destroyed after being clicked, but from this following code, it just only to the other window but doesn't close itself.

```
def pre_create_window():

    
    conn = sqlite3.connect('utube3.db')
    
    c = conn.cursor()

    
    c.execute("""Select Songs.Song,Artists.artist FROM Songs 
            INNER JOIN Artists
            ON Artists.Artist_Id = Songs.Artist_Id
            where Songs.song=?""",(result1,))
    input5 = c.fetchall()
    print(input5)
    
    global result2
    result2 = input5[0][1]
    print(result2)
    
    
    if len(input5) > 1:
        
        root3 = Toplevel(root)
        root3.iconbitmap('ytmusic.ico')
        root3.title('Youtube Music')
        
        Artist1 = []
        
        for i in input5:
            Artist1.append((i[1],i[1]))
    
        pizza = StringVar()
        pizza.set(".anything")
    
        for text, art in Artist1:
            Radiobutton(root3, text=text, variable=pizza, value=art).grid()
        
        def clicked(value):
            
            global result2
            result2 = str(value)
            #print(result2)
            
            create_window()
            root3.destroy()
            
            
        myButton = Button(root3, text="Click Me!", command=lambda: clicked(pizza.get()))
        myButton.grid()
        
        root3.mainloop()
        
    conn.commit()
    conn.close()
    
    
    create_window()
```

```
def create_window():

       root2 = Toplevel()
       root2.mainloop()
```

But, When I make `create_window()` to `#create_window()` in `def clicked(value):`

it destroyed itself, but not direct to create_window

**So, my question is how can I make it both destroy itself (current window) and direct to create_window ?**

Comment: You can try to set ```root3.destroy()``` to ```root.destroy()```

So your code will look like 





```def clicked(value):
            
            global result2
            result2 = str(value)
            #print(result2)
            
            create_window()
            root3.destroy()```

Comment: Remove `root2.mainloop()` inside `create_window()`.  You should call `mainloop()` only once.

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. This would have probably saved you from asking altogether, since you'd have probably found an issue before asking.